# Swift: Problems with PrototypeCells in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uiswitch

I have a problem with my iOS Application. I'm using Swift and XCode 6.3. I have a UITableViewController in my application and in this TableView I've created a prototype cell (Custom). In the design it looks like this:

[image]

This is how I want the cells (left the title and on the right a switch in every cell).

But my problem is, if I run the project it looks like this on my iPhone:

[image]

What do I have to do that the cell is looking like my prototype cell? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm guessing that you're using the default label (by setting the text on cell.textLabel), and that label is too wide. Subclass the cell, and add your own label with the correct constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your title label is probably overlapping the switch view. You need to set an auto-layout constraint of `horizontal spacing` between the right edge (**trailing** in auto layout language...) of the label and the left edge (**leading**) of the switch view.

**1. ctrl+drag from the label to the switch:**

[image]

**2. pick horizontal spacing:**

[image]

3. then change the `relation` to be `Greater than or equal` instead `equal`, and set the `constant` to whatever **minimum** distance you want to have between the label and the switch:

[image]

4. add all other missing constrains...

**EDIT:**
To get the label without having to subclass `UITableViewCell` you can set a tag to the label:
[image]

Then inside `cellForRow..` you can get it with `myCell.viewWithTag(999)`

Comment: I have no label there in my design I add the text by the code. If I click into this PrototypeCell it doesn't show me a label. So if there would be a label it would be easy. But anyway thank you for the answer maybe you have got an other idea.

Comment: Ok, so I would solve it like this but how do I have to set the code in my code, that the text is appearing in this new label instead of the old "ghost-label"?

Comment: The easiest way (i.e., without subclassing `UITableViewCell`) would be to set the `tag` attribute of the label view (find it on the right under Attribute Inspector) to some number (say, 999) then you can get it inside `cellForRow...` by calling `myCell.viewWithTag(999)`

Comment: I write into the cell like this, now I have to know how I can set the code that I'm writing in the new label. `cell.textLabel!.text = Items[indexPath.row]`